# Why my database displays undefined even I inserted data in POSTMAN?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, postman

Below is my code for inserting data in MYSQL in ExpressJS.

```
router.post('/user', function (req, res) {
        let sql = "INSERT INTO Member (id, Memb_ID, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Address, url) VALUES (null, '" + req.body.Memb_ID + "',  '" + req.body.First_Name + "', '" + req.body.Middle_Name + "', '" + req.body.Last_Name + "', '" + req.body.Address + "', '" + req.body.url + "')";

        myDB.query(sql, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send({
                Success: "Data inserted."
            })

        });
    });
```

It inserts data in my database but my database looks like this

[image: DB]

I don't know why it outputs like that. Here's my JSON [image]

**EDIT** :
Here is my MYSQL Table
[image: TABLE]

Comment: all column is undefined? put the image with header column. it's confusing and hard to visualize.

Comment: Hi @Yeou I updated the post. Thanks

Comment: check if you are getting all the values in request variable. you can try `console.log(req.body.Memb_ID)`. Also do `console.log(sql)`

Comment: It's just [] in the browser and no output in console. IDK why

Comment: then your data is not being submitted. check that.

Comment: Yeah it was, I fixed the issue by restarting the server and POSTMAN.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure that the following is done?

1. The `content-type` header in the request has to be `application/json`
2. Use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) (or similar libraries) to parse JSON payloads -> You can print the req.body to validate this.
3. If you can confirm that the values are accessible, I would suggest escaping query values as mentioned in https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values (or in any mysql library that you use) - especially since it is a DML query.

(Also I assume that the fieldnames used in the query match with the ones in the database and are of the right datatype.)

Comment: Uhh where should I put  content-type and application/json? I don't have both in my code.

Comment: Hi Vin, you can add that in the headers section in POSTMAN REST client.

Comment: Can you check if the req.body contains the values that you post from the REST client ? (console.log(req.body); should tell)

Comment: It worked, IDK why, I just created another window in POSTMAN and copy the values and rerun the server and POSTMAN and it worked. Also, it was printed in the console.

Comment: Cool. Let us know how it worked if you were able to troubleshoot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your image of postman call, it's clearly showing your content type is `text`.

1. Change Content-type to `application/json` in your postman call headers
2. Or you can select from body tab
   [image]

As your body content was `text` as shown in your image, it was sending a plain text that leading to undefined in DB. But the server was expecting `json`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

See wether you have added **@RequestBody** annotation in your respective method signature in Controller...

check this 1's bcz i had same issue i resolved after adding this..
it may help you and others... also...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).