# Inserted Data with Postman results in undefined values in MySQL, Inserting with Lambda does not (row is ok)

Tags: mysql, json, aws-lambda, postman, undefined

When i use my lambda function, which contains an insert to my DB, the row inserted is displayed perfectly in my DB.
But when i test the endpoint of my lambda function (given by Gateway, Post method ) with Postman, the inserted row is filled with undefined.

Below are my Postman body request (post), and my lambda test event

[image: POSTMAN request]

[image: Lambda test event]

I wanted to clarify that i already checked [Why my database displays undefined even I inserted data in POSTMAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764250/why-my-database-displays-undefined-even-i-inserted-data-in-postman) ,  i can actually do the insert with my lambda function. This is more a problem of passing down the params with Postman, for what i think, and not with the code.

Also yes, postman headers includes application/json content type [image]

Proof :

[image: mysql select]

NodeJS function  sql (Lambda)

```
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => { 
...
var user = event.username;
var email = event.email;
var password = event.password;
var sql0 = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('"+user+"','"+email+"','"+password+"','')";
 connection.query(sql0, function (error, result, fields) { ...
```

Comment: you should add all the relevant code snippets

Comment: @TomSlabbaert about my lambda function? didnt include it because it works with lambda, so i thought that was not the problem. Editing right now.

Comment: Can you check the logs that what you are receiving in events

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer how can i do that? from Postman?

Comment: Not from postman but from AWS cloudwatch--> log groups

Comment: Method request path: {}
Method request query string: {}
Method request headers: {}
Method request body before transformations: {
  "username": "mike",
  "email": "mike@gmail.com",
  "password": "banane"
}

Comment: Not of your postman, of your app.

Comment: Thanks for responding, just redid from 0 the API gateway and it worked. Dont know what was wrong with it.